# Replace images with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, image

If I had a folder full of thousands of images that were all the same size, could I take 1 image and replace all the others with that image (but retain the file names) with Ruby?
If so, how would you do that exactly?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing copying one image to many, while keeping their file names. Surely, you mean something else?

Comment: @pavium - Actually that's exactly what I mean.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if I understand your question you wish to do this:

1. Take a directory with `dog.jpg (image of a dog)`, `cat.jpg (image of a cat)` and `horse.jpg (image of a horse)`
2. Choose dog.jpg as your source image
3. Replace the image of a cat and horse with a dog while keeping their filenames
4. Resulting in a directory with `dog.jpg (image of a dog)`, `cat.jpg (image of a dog)` and `horse.jpg (image of a dog)`

You could use a function like this,

```
require 'FileUtils'

def operate_on_directory(source_image, extensions)
  Dir.glob("*.{#{extensions.join(',')}}") do |file|
    FileUtils.cp(source_image, file) unless file == source_image
  end
end

operate_on_directory("dog.jpg", ["jpg", "png"])
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want.  Thank you!